# Observable.zip with RxBinding don't return result

Tags: android, rx-android

I have two EditText, and i listening it with two observables:

```
Observable<CharSequence> emailObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(emailNew);
Observable<CharSequence> passwordObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(passwordNew);
```

I want to zip values from this fields to do some action when both values will valid.

So i wrote:

```
Observable.zip(emailObservable, passwordObservable, 
(charSequence, charSequence2) -> "test")
          .subscribe(result -> Timber.e("Result:" + result));
```

But it returns result only when second field data changed. When i type something at first field, it is not working.

Same result if i write:

```
emailObservable
    .zipWith(passwordObservable, (email, password) -> email + " " + password)
    .subscribe(result -> Timber.e(result);});
```

It returns correct values from first field, but return nothing if i type on it.

The answer must be ease, but now i can't understand what i do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i replace `zip` to `combineLatest` and it works somehow:

```
Observable.combineLatest(emailObservable, passwordObservable,
                (charSequence, charSequence2) -> new String[]{charSequence.toString(), charSequence2.toString()})
                .subscribe(result -> {
                    boolean isEmailValid = isValidEmail(result[0]);
                    boolean isPasswordValid = isValidPassword(result[1]);
                });
```

Comment: I think the problem was because zip waits for both observables to emit - and then combines those two values. What happened was you typed into one edit text so it emitted but zip was still waiting for the second edit text to emit. Yeah combine latest makes more sense for your use case - combines latest emitted values - so as soon as you type someting in first edit text it starts validating